# Force GHC using local files

Tags: haskell, build, ghc, cabal

I'm making some "experiments" on a haskell module and I have a problem with a source file I wish to modify.

I have many reasons to think that GHC seek the installed (with cabal) library on my system and not the local sources files.
I deleted the `*.o` files locally and the other source files in this module are not rebuild by GHC.

**Can I force GHC to use the local sources files of a module or ignore an installed module in particular?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, one of your modules is named the same as a module from one of the libraries you have installed. If that is the case, the simplest way to hide that library is probably to use a [cabal sandbox](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes).

Comment: *Don't*. Avoid name clashes. Sure you can work around them but it's a lot of work when you simply could avoid all the hassle by choosing  a unique name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `ghc -hide-package evil-package`. Or you can hide the package temporarily with `ghc-pkg hide evil-package`, and then undo it later with `ghc-pkg expose evil-package`.